# Create a Tag with an input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input for writing tags. My problem is that I wanted to write in the input any name of tag and by pressing enter or clicking the button, the tag was created in the box below as shown in the image.

**What I have**

[image: Image 1]

**What I want when I press enter key or button plus**

[image: Image 2]

**Final**

[image: Image 3]

```css
.TagInput {
    width: 400px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #FAFAFB 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-    messaging-ui-color-shapes/128/add-circle-blue-512.png) no-repeat scroll 370px 3px;
}

.card {
    width: 435px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header header">
         <h1> Tags </h1>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body">
         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control TagInput" placeholder="Tag your product...">
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript? You can create a new `div`, set the `innerText` and append it to your container.

Comment: Further are you using jQuery or any kind of SPA like Angular, Vue or React? Should it work only for this input tag or for all inputs that have the class TagInput e.g.?

Comment: I was only able to insert the tags inside the input, but it's not what I intended, so my javascript wouldn't do anything :(

Comment: Im work with angular

Comment: Okay now we are getting closer - please edit your question and give us more details please. Are you using AngularJS or Angular2+? Can you provide a bit more code from what you tried out? For example how you achieved to get the tags inside the input tag?

Comment: To put the tags inside the input I used the bootstrap tagsinput, however is not what I want, the intended is in the last image of the post :(

Comment: version of angular?

Comment: version 7... i can use javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with bootstrap to be honest. But maybe you can try out an Angular solution. This could be a starting point:

**CSS**

```
.your-class{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background:#eee;
  padding:5px;
  min-width:50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius:30px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let tag of tags" class="your-class">
    {{tag}} <span class="delete-entry" (click)="deleteTagFromProduct(tag)">x</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<input (change)="addTagToProduct($event)" class="form-control TagInput"/>
```

**Typescript**

```
private tags:string[] = [];

private addTagToProduct( $event ):void {
  this.tags.push($event.target.value);
  $event.target.value = "";
}

private deleteTagFromProduct( tag:string ):void {
  this.tags = this.tags.filter( (a) => a!==tag );
}
```

Comment: It worked now to change the design of the tags created how can I do? Create a new class?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't know if you already have a class with such a styling but again as a starting point i put you a class into the post. Further i added an example how you can delete tags from by clicking the little x behind the tag.

Comment: No problem! - let me know if you miss something